# I can't run swift in docker using ubuntu14.04

Tags: swift, docker

I run a docker using ubuntu14.04 image

and I config the environment in the container by https://swift.org/download/

just install clang and libicu-dev the add the key and extrac the swift

I get this error when I use swift

`$ swift

Welcome to Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM 17c4c6cf7a, Clang 4ca9e01a7c, Swift 13a9908f8d). Type :help for assistance.
1> l+1
[1]   346 segmentation fault  swift`

when I try to complie a file, I get this

`$ swiftc hello.swift

<unknown>:0: error: opening import file for module 'SwiftShims': No such file or directory`

I get the error messages when I use privilege or not

Comment: If you try with already existing image ? for exemple https://hub.docker.com/r/swiftdocker/swift/~/dockerfile/

Comment: I know it,,my step is same as it..,,the problem is not solve,.I try to contack the author

Answer (score 0):

First you have to run your docker container in previlege mode `--privileged=true`.
Please refer [Running Swift in Docker container](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-54)

There are specific installation instrutions for Ubuntu 14.04 
Please have a look into this link [Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/)

```
sudo apt-get install git cmake ninja-build clang python uuid-dev libicu-dev icu-devtools libbsd-dev libedit-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev swig libpython-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config libblocksruntime-dev
sudo apt-get install clang-3.6 -y
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-3.6 100
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-3.6 100
```

Comment: I have seen the swift instrutions in github,,I do it ,and I also give the --privileged to my container,but not work..

Comment: It worked for Swift Perview  Edition(Previews Swift 3.0 Preview 6). Could you please give a try on it.

Comment: I try it,,I download the previews swift and upgrade clang to 3.6,but I get this problem `segmentation fault  swift` when I use swift CLI